# How can I make a paypal payment to a site user in D7? (How to SEND money to a site user through Paypal?)

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, payment, commerce

How can I make a paypal payment to a site user in D7?

Currently I use commerce and commerce_paypal with express checkout. Is there a way to do these payments without installing any other modules?

I have already created a 'paypal account' field on user profile as I definitely need a paypal account to send payments to I'm looking for the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MassPayment API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayUsingAPI/) or [Implicit](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) send money from Adaptive Payments.

- Masspay API helps to send money from your PayPal account to multiple receivers.
- Implicit Payments is that, in which your application is both the sender of a payment and the caller of the Adaptive Payments API. You would need to create a application at apps.paypal.com to acquire this feature.

Comment: I'd like to send money programmatically not to receive.

Comment: /You can use MassPayment API or Implicit send money from Adaptive Payments.https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/